# Variable in Php Pdo not define

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have an array in pdo its not showing any output say varibale image not define varible $pic not define....
Below is the code please tell me where i am wrong....

```
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if(count($rows) > 0) {
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $image = $row['file'];
    $pic = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg',$image);
    }
    }
```

i am echo this array using for loop but variable define error....

```
 <?php 
  for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
   echo"<option  data-img-src=\"$pic[$i]\" value=\"$pic[$i]\" ></option>";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$pic` is defined within the scope of `while` loop. Declare it on the top and it will work. Older versions of php worked but the latest one gives exceptions.

```
  $pic="";
  $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  if(count($rows) > 0) {
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $image = $row['file'];
    $pic = array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg',$image);
    }
  }
```

Comment: its not working i am writing array only for $image and get data for $image in while so how can i write outside from loop/

Answer (score 0):

You're using `FETCH_OBJ` style then use the output as if it's an array, causing an error.

This could go two ways:

- Changing the fetch style to `FETCH_ASSOC` so that you can use it as an array

  ```
  while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $image = $row['file'];
  ```
- Or change the `$image` line so that it uses the `$row` variable as an object.

  ```
  while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  $image = $row->file;
  ```